# Generic method with dynamically selected parameter in predicate

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, predicate

I have many objects of diffrent type and i need to check few diffrent properties from each of them in the same way. I want to use this method inside object initializer like this:

```
collection.GroupBy(x => x.Identifier)
.Select(group => new SomeType 
{
    Identifier = group.Key,
    Quantity = group.Sum(i => i.Quantity),
    Type = MY_METHOD_HERE(group),
    Name = MY_METHOD_HERE(group)
})
```

Strongly typed example for one of the properties:

```
private ItemType CheckItemTypeConsistency(IGrouping<string, Item> group)
    {
        if (group.Any(x => x.ItemType != group.First().ItemType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Item with number {group.Key} is inconsistent", nameof(Item.ItemType));
        }
        else
        {
            return group.First().ItemType;
        }
    }
```

But i also have other property in Item that needs to be checked in the same way with diffrent type, so i have similar method but `.ItemType` is changed everywhere to `.Name` and return type is `string`.

I also have diffrent object type that i need to use it for, so in another method `Item` is changed to `Vehicle`.

How to create generic method like that?
I tried something like this:

```
private TElement CheckConsistency<TKey, TElement>(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> group, (maybe something here?))
    {
        if (group.Any(x => x.(what here?) != group.First().(what here?)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Element with number {group.Key} is inconsistent");
        }
        else
        {
            return group.First();
        }
    }
```

I solved problem with returning value by returning whole item so i can just `CheckConsistency().Property` when invoking this method.
But i dont know what to do with `(what here?)`.

I thought that maybe i can put something in `(maybe something here?)` that would be somehow used in place of `(what here?)`?

Any ideas? I'm not sure about reflection because this method could be called easily more than 1000 times depending on collection size and number of unique entries.

**@Edit:**
Lets say it's something like merging data from two files. For example 2 data sets of items where quantity is added together for items with the same identifier etc. but some properties should be the same like name and if they are diffrent then there's something wrong and i need to throw an error.
There are diffrent sets of data with completly diffrent properties like vehicles, but rules are similar, some fields are just added together etc, some must be identical.

Comment: Can you make all your classes inherit from a single parent? If so then you could then have the parent have a method(s) to check consistency and children will implement it however they please.

Comment: No, there are some properties that are not common amongs them and there still would be a problem of using this method for other properties of the same object.

Comment: You could just pass in a `Func` that gets the required property?

Comment: you mean passing `x => x.ItemType != group.First().ItemType` as argument? I could but still really repetitive writing whole condition again and again and there is risk of mistake like `==` instead of `!=` and its confussing to make method that accepts all kind of predicates but don't really work as it should if you pass diffrent predicate

Comment: No, I meant to pass in `x => x.ItemType` only

Comment: But if i just pass `x => x.ItemType` as selector i will have `selector != ???` i could propably pass second selector or just TElement but `group.First()` would be repetitive part and i'm still worrying that this still will result in method that needs to be used in very specific way for it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an accessor function and genericizing the property type and object type, you have:

```
private TProp CheckConsistency<TClass, TProp>(IGrouping<string, TClass> group, Func<TClass, TProp> propFn) {
    var firstPropValue = propFn(group.First());
    if (group.Any(x => firstPropValue == null ? propFn(x) == null : !propFn(x).Equals(firstPropValue))) {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Item with number {group.Key} is inconsistent");
    }
    else {
        return firstPropValue;
    }
}
```

Which you can use like:

```
var ans = collection.GroupBy(x => x.Identifier)
                    .Select(group => new SomeType {
                        Identifier = group.Key,
                        Quantity = group.Sum(i => i.Quantity),
                        Type = CheckConsistency(group, x => x.ItemType),
                        Name = CheckConsistency(group, x => x.Name)
                    });
```

If it is important to include the proper argument name in the exception, you could pass it in, take in an `Expression<Func<>>` and pull out the name, then compile the argument to a lambda to use (may be slow), or use reflection instead of a lambda property accessor (also possibly slow).

To use Reflection, I recommend caching the compiled function so you don't constantly re-compile each time the method is called:

```
// [Expression] => [Func]
Dictionary<LambdaExpression, Delegate> propFnCache = new Dictionary<LambdaExpression, Delegate>();

private TProp CheckConsistency<TClass, TProp>(IGrouping<string, TClass> group, Expression<Func<TClass, TProp>> propExpr) {
    Func<TClass,TProp> propFn;
    if (propFnCache.TryGetValue(propExpr, out var propDel))
        propFn = (Func<TClass, TProp>)propDel;
    else {
        propFn = propExpr.Compile();
        propFnCache.Add(propExpr, propFn);
    }

    var firstPropValue = propFn(group.First());
    if (group.Any(x => !propFn(x).Equals(firstPropValue))) {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Item with number {group.Key} is inconsistent", ((MemberExpression)propExpr.Body).Member.Name);
    }
    else {
        return firstPropValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already did something similar, i forgot to send it here. Actually Instead of equals you should make your own method for this to avoid null reference exception when `propFn(x)` is null, because if this and firstPropValue are both null it should work and return true and if only one is null it should return false. I return property name in exception with `typeof(TProp).Name`

Comment: @kkamil4sz I added null handling. Note that `typeof(TProp).Name` will be something like `System.String` which is not terribly helpful.

Comment: Oh right it's good when you have your own class, but if its something like string it's not really helpfull. How can i get property name from propFn?

Comment: @kkamil4sz I added an `Expression<>` version that caches the compilation result so it doesn't have to constantly compile when called and pulls the member name from the `Expression<Func<>>`.